# {"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}

Tags: android, facebook, image, post, types

```
private void postToWall(String msg) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        // parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");

        JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

        try {

            byte[] data = null;

            Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.bluerib);
            // Bitmap bi =
            // BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://demos.com/LangGuage/medal_1.png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();

            // Bundle params = new Bundle();
            // params.putByteArray("picture", data);
            attachment.put("type", "image");
            // attachment.put("picture", data);
            attachment.put("name", "LangGuage");
            attachment.put("message", msg);
            attachment.put("src", "http://demos.com/LangGuage/medal_1.png");
            attachment.put("href", "http://www.abc.com");
            // attachment.put("href",
            // "http://hwsdemos.com/LangGuage/medal_1.png");

            parameters.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
            String response = facebook.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST");

            System.out.println("----responce" + response);

            if (response.contains("Duplicate status message")) {
                progressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                resp = 1;

            } else if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false") || response.contains("error")) {
                Log.d("error", "error response");
            } else {
                progressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                resp = 0;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Posting fail");

            e.printStackTrace();
            // finish();
        }

    }
```

My app is supporting single sign-in for facebook. I don't want to use dialogs. 
Whenever I try to post an image and message together in a attachment I catch:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}
```

Comment: remove this `attachment.put("type", "image");`

Comment: I checked after removing this line.but still get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

See the docs for a photos graph POST request here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Your image data should go into the "source" field, and the only other available fields are "message", "place' and "no_story". The "src", "name", "href" are not valid fields.

Comment: Is it still true? I read that you can post an image via an url, in which case you you "src" instead of "source":
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos/

Comment: You can post an image using either "source" or "url".