# Upload Photo in Facebook - {"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sencha-touch

I'm creating an app to publish photos in Facebook. With my code I receive this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}

I know that the login is ok....but after the upload give me this error...

Someone  can help me please?

`ciaopoint2.Globals.imagefinal = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        //Verifico lo Stato del Login
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
              FB.api( 
                    '/photos',
                            'POST',
                            {

                                message: 'CiaoPoint ti ringrazia',
                                source: ciaopoint2.Globals.imagefinal
                            },

                            function (response) {
                              if (response && !response.error) {
                                /* handle the result */
                              }
                            }
                        );`

```
        }
        else {

            FB.login(function(response) {

                if (response.authResponse) {

                    FB.api(
                       '/photos',
                        'POST',
                        {                                
                            message: 'CiaoPoint ti ringrazia',
                            source: ciaopoint2.Globals.imagefinal
                        },                           
                        function (response) {
                          if (response && !response.error) {
                            /* handle the result */
                          }
                        }
                    );                         

                }
                else {
                     alert("Non puoi loggarti in Facebook");
                }

            }, {scope: 'email'});

        }

    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428959/errormessage324-requires-upload-file-typeoauthexception-code

Comment: Help me please.......